# exponential decay with scipy just gives step function

Tags: plot, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to do an exponential fit with a set of data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt


def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(x / -b) + c


epr_data = np.loadtxt('T2_text', skiprows=1)

time = epr_data[:, 1]
intensity = epr_data[:, 2]


optimizedParameters, pcov = opt.curve_fit(func, time, intensity)
print(optimizedParameters)
plt.plot(time, intensity, func(time, *optimizedParameters), label="fit")

plt.show()
```

but i just get this step function and these parameters:

[1.88476367e+05 1.00000000e+00 6.49563230e+03]

the plot with "fit"
[image: the plot with "fit"]

as well as this error message:

```
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated'
```

EDIT:

https://pastebin.com/GTTGf0ed

i want to plot the time and first row with intensity

the graph after your suggestion
[image: the graph after your suggestion]

edit 2:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt


def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(x / -b) + c


epr_data = np.loadtxt('T2_text', skiprows=1)

time = epr_data[:, 1]
intensity = epr_data[:, 2]

c0 = np.mean(intensity[-10:])
a0 = intensity[0]-c0
th = time[np.searchsorted(-intensity+c0, -0.5*a0)]
b0 = th / np.log(2)

optimizedParameters, pcov = opt.curve_fit(func, time, intensity, p0=(a0, b0, c0))
print(optimizedParameters)
plt.plot(time, intensity, label='data')
plt.plot(time, func(time, *optimizedParameters), label="fit")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix your `plot` function call.  To plot two curves with one call, you have to give the `x` and `y` values for each curve:

```
plt.plot(time, intensity, time, func(time, *optimizedParameters), label="fit")
```

For labeling, it might be simpler to call `plot` twice:

```
plt.plot(time, intensity, label="data")
plt.plot(time, func(time, *optimizedParameters), label="fit")
```

It would be easier to address the warning generated by `curve_fit` if we had your data.  Experience shows, however, that it is most likely that the default initial guess of the parameters used by `curve_fit` (which is all 1s) is just a really bad guess.

Try helping `curve_fit` by giving it a better starting point for its numerical optimization routine.  The following bit of code shows how you can  compute rough guesses for `a`, `b` and `c`.  Pass these to `curve_fit` with the argument `p0=(a0, b0, c0)`.

```
# Assume that the time series is long enough that the tail
# has flattened out to approximately random noise around c.
c0 = np.mean(intensity[-10:])

# This assumes time[0] is 0.
a0 = intensity[0] - c0

# Rough guess of the half-life.
th = time[np.searchsorted(-intensity+c0, -0.5*a0)]
b0 = th / np.log(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data is in a edit. The graph has changed after I changed the plot function call but even after the better starting points it's just a step function again. I'll add a image in the original post.

Comment: Have you tried it again with `a0`, `b0` and `c0` as shown above?

Comment: Yes I did. I attached the graph in the original post. I used the variable time for the x in your little bit of code (in the xh variable), is that correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'll fix that to match your original code.

Comment: Ok, but still the graph looks strange. Did the data help you?

Comment: I couldn't access the data--google wants me to log in.

Comment: Ok maybe pastebin will work. its pretty long so I didn't want to include it in the original post

Comment: With your data, and with `p0=(a0, b0, c0)` computed as above, `curve_fit` returns the parameters `[191011.05421093,  12437.36101452,  -5174.47593186]` with no warnings, and the plot looks reasonable.

Comment: Ok i got it now. I changed the func by accident to a * np.exp(-b * x) + c. Now it works! Could you explain why this caused an issue? Many thanks!

Comment: Underlying `curve_fit` is a numerical minimization algorithm.  Such algorithms almost always do best when given a reasonable guess of the solution.  The default guess of `p0` in `curve_fit` is (1, 1, 1), which for your data is a *terrible* guess.    Your time values range from 0 to 200000, and with `b = 1`, all but two of the values of `exp(-time/b)` underflow to 0, so the algorithm simply can't calculate correct values of the function to be minimized.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. The values are way to large for that guess, got it. Thank you very much!!!